# how to load sources with different qualities in jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

I would like to know about this question. I tried some ways but not useful.
The following is my code:

```
player.load([{
    title: "test line",
    sources: [
        {
            file: message.content,
            provider: "${base}/resources/web/plugins/jwplayer6/HLSProvider6.swf",
            type: "hls",
            label: "240",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            file: message.content,
            provider: "${base}/resources/web/plugins/jwplayer6/HLSProvider6.swf",
            type: "hls",
            label: "360"
        }
    ]
}]);
player.play();
```

Can someone help me?

**In addition:**
I also want to know how to set hlslabel? What I set is useless.

Comment: hlslabels will only work in our built in hls implementation, and the loading code above will not work unless you also use our built in hls, and it looks like you are using a 3rd party provider here. Try without that provider.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Without that provider, can I use hls streaming?

Comment: See http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430218-using-hls-streaming

Comment: ^ Exactly. It is built into the player (premium and higher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use FlowPlayer instead of JWPlayer and it solved my problem.